# Sending data with multi step form to wp database

Tags: database, forms

I have a multi step form and I need to save data from each step to the db. First step is contact details and by clicking button "Next" data should be saved to db.

In my form template I have js code for collecting and sanding data to php file

```
function Send_Data_Post_In() {
            var name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
            var lastname = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
            var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

            var httpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpr.open("POST", "/post-expance.php", true);
            httpr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            httpr.send("&name=" + name + "&lastname=" + lastname + "$email" + email + "$phone" + phone);
            console.log(httpr);

        }
```

And php file is

```
include_once '/wp-config.php';

$name = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO step_form (first_name, last_name, email, phone) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$email', '$phone');";

$result = mysqli_query($wpdb, $sql);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to save data from each step to the db but it's doesn't work now

Comment: You shouldn't be making direct requests to PHP files in your theme or plugin, it's a security risk and not how WP works.  You also don't need to store each steps data in the database to track things across each step. Instead the solution you need is not a WP solution but a generic form based solution involving hidden fields